# Trying to compile pset2 readability from cs50 .. Gives same errors "use of undeclared identifier" would appreciate any suggestions

Tags: c, cs50, undeclared-identifier

Trying to compile pset2 readability from cs50 .. Have no idea whats wrong. Showing me lots of errors. I tried to fix them, but it gives new ones. Started to think that the problem might be something completely different. So I'm stuck and cant find the way to fix it.  Would appreciate any help! Thank you!

```
    int main(void)
      {
      string text = get_string("Text:");
      int letterCount = 0;
      int wordCount = 0;
      int sentCount = 0;
      for(int n = 0; len = strlen(text); n < len; n++)
      {
        if(isalpha(text[n]))
           letterCount++;
        if ((n == 0 && text[n] != ' ') || (n != len - 1 && s[n] == ' ' && s[n +1] != ' '))
           wordCount++;
        if ((text[n] == '!') || (text[n] == '.') || (text[n] == '?'))
           sentCount++;
      }

      //Average number of letters per 100 words
      float avLetters = (letterCount / (float) wordCount) * 100;
      //Average number sentences per 100 words
      float avSent = (sentCount  / (float) wordCount) * 100;
    // find the index
    int Grade = round(0.0588 * avLetters  - 0.296 * avSent - 15.8);

      if(Grade < 16)
           printf("Grade %i\n", Grade);
      else if ( Grade >= 16)
           printf("Grade 16+");
      else
           printf("Before Grade 1");

}



Readability.c:12:18: error: use of undeclared identifier 'len'
  for(int n = 0; len = strlen(text); n < len; n++)
                 ^
Readability.c:12:42: error: use of undeclared identifier 'len'
  for(int n = 0; len = strlen(text); n < len; n++)
                                         ^
Readability.c:12:45: error: expected ')'
  for(int n = 0; len = strlen(text); n < len; n++)
                                            ^
Readability.c:12:6: note: to match this '('
  for(int n = 0; len = strlen(text); n < len; n++)
     ^
Readability.c:12:47: error: use of undeclared identifier 'n'
  for(int n = 0; len = strlen(text); n < len; n++)

            ^
```

Comment: Its good that you posted minimal-reproducible-code (excluding the get_string function :( ) the question quality will be improved if you can post the errors you are encountering.

Comment: Welcome to SO. It would help a lot if you shared the names of the undeclared identifiers? If you get lots of them in such a tiny piece of code, I would assume you missed to include all the headers.

Comment: You can edit your question to include the missing information. Just click the `edit` button below the tags of your question.

Comment: Also `for(int n = 0; len = strlen(text); n < len; n++)` -> `for (int n = 0; text[n]; n++)` `text` is a *nul-terminated* string, just iterate over the characters until the `'\0'` (ASCII `0`) is reached. (that's the purpose of the *nul-terminating* character -- it allows you to scan-forward in the string and know when you have reached the end `:)`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed your compilation errors, you can compare it with your version to see what went wrong.  here is the [link](https://cee.studio/200527-dR3/DXVVP) to build and run the fixed code.

```
#include<cs50.h>

int main(void) {
  string text = get_string("Text:");
  int letterCount = 0;
  int wordCount = 0;
  int sentCount = 0;
  for (int n = 0, len = strlen(text); n < len; n++) {
    if (isalpha(text[n]))
      letterCount++;
    if ((n == 0 && text[n] != ' ') ||
        (n != len - 1 && text[n] == ' ' && text[n + 1] != ' '))
      wordCount++;
    if ((text[n] == '!') || (text[n] == '.') || (text[n] == '?'))
      sentCount++;
  }

  // Average number of letters per 100 words
  float avLetters = (letterCount / (float)wordCount) * 100;
  // Average number sentences per 100 words
  float avSent = (sentCount / (float)wordCount) * 100;
  // find the index
  int Grade = round(0.0588 * avLetters - 0.296 * avSent - 15.8);

  if (Grade < 16)
    printf("Grade %i\n", Grade);
  else if (Grade >= 16)
    printf("Grade 16+");
  else
    printf("Before Grade 1");
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but It didn't help with the errors.. Fixing the loop by changing it to for(int n = 0; text[n]; n++) - did. At least I've been able to compile it. But now there is a logical bug.. Struggling to find it..